# fastap how to filter sqlalchemyi query by json field

Tags: sqlalchemy, filtering, fastapi, jsonfield

i am trying to filter by json-filed in fastapi using sqlalchemy

class Database_Model(Base):
**tablename** = "database_model"
data = Column(JSON, nullable=False)

@router.get("/test/")
def test(
db: Session = Depends(get_db)
):

```
    return (
        db.query(Database_Model)
            .filter(Database_Model.data["test_field"] == "value").all()
    )
```

Comment: And what is your question? What is not working?

Comment: It‘s not able to filter like this code!